# Error : 14 UNAVAILABLE : Connect Failed

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am getting the below error while deploying the business network using multi org env.

**Error : Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Responses from attempted peer comms was an error : Error : 14 UNAVAILABLE : Connect Failed.**

Quick background of my env:

I have a local ubuntu machine with Composer installed.

I have Multi Org setup installed with Hyperledger Fabric which includes 3 Orgs with 9 peers in 9 physical machines.

The connection profile has been used here to deploy the business network application from my local ubuntu machine.

Cards have been created sucessfully with the given Connection Profile and also imported successfully. Created 3 connection profiles for the 3 organizations. Also used TLS certs in the connection profiles.

Please guide me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually seen when the CLI cannot connect to the Fabric using the addresses specified in the connection.json file.  Either the Fabric containers are not started or they are not accessible to the CLI via the addresses specified.

Perhaps the addresses are wrong? If you are using 9 physical machines are the addresses resolving? are there firewall issues?